# The DataGridview Always Empty Although the Datatable returns the values that I want

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I don't Understand what is going on :( I'm struggling with this code 4 days ago...

I have 2 methods that returns TWO datatables, I Merge them in one table, and bind a BindingSource to the DT then bind the Datagridview to the Bindingsource

```
private void chld_LogByName_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgvLogByName.DataSource = bs1;
            PreviewKN(); PreviewRD();
            dt1.Merge(dt2);
            bs1.DataSource = dt1;
        }
```

So I can Search in the DGV like that:

```
private void txtLName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dgvLogByName.DataSource;
            string columnName = dgvLogByName.Columns[5].Name.ToString();
            bs.Filter = columnName + " like '%" + txtFName.Text + "%'";
            dgvLogByName.DataSource = bs;
          }
```

THIS WORKS PERFECT...

But when I turn to that one, it works until it load the LocalDataTable, but it doesn't bind the able to the DGV, so the DT has rows, but the DGV has 0.

```
private void txtFName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (dt1 != null && dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataRow[] dr = dt1.Select("F_Name LIKE '%"+ txtFName.Text +"%'");
                    DataTable localTable = new DataTable();

                    if (dr.Length > 0)
                    {
                        dgvLogByName.DataSource = null;

                        foreach (DataRow row in dr)
                        {
                            localTable.ImportRow(row);
                        }
                        dgvLogByName.DataSource = localTable; 
                        dgvLogByName.Refresh();
                    }
```

Please Help..

Comment: Use `localTable.Rows.Add(row);` instead of `localTable.ImportRow(row);`

Comment: localTable.Rows.Add(row) I can't use this method because the table rows are belong to the mainDataTable, so the best way is to use the ImportRow method,

Comment: And this is not the problem, the "LocalTable" get the Rows and everything perfect till that part. The problem is the DataGridView doesn't display the result as if I'm doing nothing. 
I beleive that this is because it is already bind to another datasource in the PageLoad

Comment: are you missing  ` dgvLogByName.DataBind() `  I guss.